# Setting up dynamic DNS for linked router

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, dynamic-dns

I have a 'main' router that receives the internet signal from the ISP and another one in my room, connected with a cable. 
The main router is running its original firmware and is very limited in its features, unfortunately I can not change this router, since my phone company has some hardcoded stuff in there and the internet will only work with this router. My second router is running [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware.

Now I need to set up dynamic DNS, so I can access my NAS machine remotely, which is connected to the second router. As mentioned, this can't be done with the main router, due to its limited features. DHCP is turned off on the second router, since it gets its IP from the main one.

Is there a possibility to set up dynamic DNS on the second router, without changing any (or much) on the main router?

Maybe as a side note: I live in Germany, don't know if the set up of the routers are different in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a solution. First, register account with dyndns. Then install `curl` on your dd-wrt router. Then add to the `cron` at dd-wrt router the following task:

```
curl --silent --insecure http://username:password@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=yourhostname
```

If your ISP does transparent proxying then send request to the port 8245 instead of 80. Remember that you should not update your address too often as dyndns will blacklist you.

You may find the protocol specification [here](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/) for more details.